# How to link to native Google Maps iOS app from mobile Safari browser

Tags: google-maps, native, kml

I read somewhere (I've forgotten where) that it is now possible to link to the native Google Maps iOS app from the mobile Safari browser by using the maps:// protocol and that the app will now allow the importation of a KML file.  I have tried several different linking URLs but I can't seem to get any of them to work.  Does anyone know the correct format of this URL using the maps:// protocol with a KML file?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see there is no such option.

[Apple Developer Documentation on Map Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

You can start the Google Maps iOS native app by just redirecting to the Google Maps website:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino">Cupertino</a>
```

Regarding the KML the native app will not pick it up (from the link above):

> The rules for creating a valid map link are as follows: ...
>
> - A parameter cannot be q=* if the value is a URL (so KML is not picked up). ...

Answer (score 0):

[Apple URL Scheme Reference: Map Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1)

```
http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino
```

Note: since iOS 6, you have to convert all map requests from "maps.google.com" to "maps.apple.com" for the iOS map to activate.

Answer (score -1):

Starting in iOs 6, you should link via HTTP to maps.apple.com, such as:

> http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino

If accessed from a non-iOs device, that link currently redirects to the equivalent Google Maps search. In the future, Apple might do a web-based map viewer of their own.

See full documentation here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html